# Same Fragments in FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am developing an ExpenseManager app in android, where I am implementing a `fragmentActivity`. This `fragment` shows the account summary page with details such as Account Balance, Account Last Transaction Amount and other details.

The `AccountSummary Activity` is a multi tab activity implemented with `ViewPager`, `ActionBar`, `FragmentPageAdapter` and `FragmentActivity`.

The layout of summary page will be common for all the accounts and only the data will get changed depending which account user has selected.

Now, I want to implement this activity where I can reuse/ duplicate the same `fragment` layout (not the instance) across all the accounts or (`ActionBar` Tabs). When the user selects any tab from `actionBar`, it should load/show/display a fragment along with that account data.

(I understand that I need to create dynamic `Fragment` with different `TagName` and need to replace with the help of `FragmentTransaction`; for some reason, this solution doesn't work).

This is similar to the application on [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expensemanager) with the App layout as [Url](https://lh3.ggpht.com/TJEwUuG1Gxh87l8Pwn9Jj6H8AZuoH9_sQ1yllkh7bBmpw77mfJjFhg7f0X6EEjq7ng=h900-rw)

Could someone post a solution by using an example code ? I've been struggling to find a solution, but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT**

**AccountSummaryTabActivity.java**

```
public class AccountSummaryTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager = null;
    ActionBar actionBar = null; 
    AccountSummaryTabAdapter accSummaryAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_summary_tab);

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Account, Integer> simpleAccountDao = dbHelper.getSimpleAccountDataDao();
        List<Account> accountList = simpleAccountDao.queryForAll();

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.accountSummaryPager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        accSummaryAdapter = new AccountSummaryTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        accSummaryAdapter.setCount(accountList.size());

        viewPager.setAdapter(accSummaryAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        String[] accountNameArr = new String[accountList.size()];
        Integer i=1;
        for (Account account : accountList) {

            if(account.getIsPrimaryAcc().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                accountNameArr[0] = account.getName();
            else
                accountNameArr[i++] = account.getName();
        }

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String accountName : accountNameArr) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(accountName).setTabListener(this));
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getStringExtra("selectedAccNameTab")==null)
            intent.putExtra("selectedAccNameTab", accountNameArr[0]);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("onTabSelected "+tab.getText());

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Account, Integer> simpleAccountDao = dbHelper.getSimpleAccountDataDao();
        List<Account> accountList = simpleAccountDao.queryForAll();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("selectedAccNameTab", tab.getText());

        accSummaryAdapter = new AccountSummaryTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        accSummaryAdapter.setCount(accountList.size());
        viewPager.setAdapter(accSummaryAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("onTabUnselected "+tab.getText());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        System.out.println("onTabReselected "+tab.getText());
    }
}
```

**AccountSummaryTabAdapter.java**

```
public class AccountSummaryTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    FragmentManager fm=null;
    Integer count = 0;

    public AccountSummaryTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm=fm;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count){
        this.count=count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch (arg0){
            default :{

                AccountSummaryFragment fragment = new AccountSummaryFragment();
                return fragment;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

**AccountSummaryFragment.java**

```
public class AccountSummaryFragment extends Fragment {

    public AccountSummaryFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account_summary, container, false);

        String accountName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedAccNameTab");

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        RuntimeExceptionDao<Account, Integer> simpleAccountDao = dbHelper.getSimpleAccountDataDao();
        List<Account> accountList = simpleAccountDao.queryForEq("name", accountName);

        Account defaultAcc = accountList.get(0);
        String[] accountNameArr = new String[]{"Monthly","Quaterly","Half Yearly","Yearly"};

        TextView balanceTxVw = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.accountBalanceTxVw);
        Double balance = defaultAcc.getBalance();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        balanceTxVw.setText(df.format(balance));

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, accountNameArr);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**activity_account_summary_tab.xml Layout file**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/accountSummaryPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: I have added the code here. Basically i am changing the reinitializing the adapter class each time, a Tab is selected. So that i can get Tab Selected account details. But this has some performance hit and i can see lags while swiping account summary fragments

Answer (score 0):

The most likely way to solve this problem is to do the following:

- Since you have the same layout for most of the accounts;
- You can indeed use the same fragment but then you should keep track of which tab is selected.
- That tab (int) will be passed back to the TabsPagerAdapter. Next;
- Based on that integer value, you should return the same fragment but with a different Extra value - for instance say tab 2.
- Inside onAttach of your fragment, you can getArguments() or extras and switch on it to get the correct data for that particular fragment.
- After using that particular integer to get the correct values, you can assign values to the class variables - that implies that you should make them class-level variables.

I hope that helps a bit. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Well, the no of fragments are not fixed. Because the user can add as many as accounts he wants. and The adapter works on fixed no of fragments. I have posted the code here, let me know for modifications